# Delphi tbackgroundworker component create event

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

How can i create a event in the tbackgroundworker?
This is what i tried but the event doesn't works:

```
unit Main;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, backgroundworker;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    BackgroundWorker: TBackgroundWorker;
    procedure BackgroundWorkerWork(Worker: TBackgroundWorker);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure BackgroundWorkerWork(Worker: TBackgroundWorker);
begin
  showmessage('HOI');
end;

procedure TForm1.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
BackgroundWorker.Cancel;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
BackgroundWorker.execute;
end;

end.
```

I think it doesn't works because there isn't a link between the backgroundworker.tworkevent and the procedure BackgroundWorkerWork(Worker: TBackgroundWorker) procedure.
But how can i fix this? i don't know how i can add a event with the backgroundworker

Comment: What exactly is `TBackgroundWorker`?

Comment: @David: http://www.delphiarea.com/products/delphi-components/backgroundworker/

Comment: Within 30 seconds of examining the source code of this component, I found it calls TerminateThread: a BIG no-no that always leads to undefined behavior.  That ended my investigation as now I don't trust this component to do the right thing without thorough review/revision.  See: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150814-00/?p=91811

Answer (score 3):

It "doesn't work" (which is not a good problem description) because you've declared the `BackgroundWorkerWork` event as a method of the form here:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    BackgroundWorker: TBackgroundWorker;
    procedure BackgroundWorkerWork(Worker: TBackgroundWorker);
    ...
  end
```

But declared it as a stand alone procedure here (notice there is no `TForm1` before the name of the procedure:

```
procedure BackgroundWorkerWork(Worker: TBackgroundWorker);
```

The easiest way to create the event handler properly is to use the Object Inspector's Events tab; just double-click the event you want to create the handler for, and the IDE will generate the declaration and an empty implementation for it if it doesn't exist, and then take you to the implementation. In this case, it would have generated this:

```
procedure TForm1.BackgroundWorkerWork(Worker: TBackgroundWorker);
begin

end;
```

If you're not dropping the `TBackgroundWorker` component on a form, but are creating it at runtime, you still do it basically the same way.

- Declare the event in the form's `private` section:

  ```
  type
    TForm1 = class(TForm)
      // Other stuff added by IDE
    private
      BackgroundWorker: TBackgroundWorker;
      procedure BackgroundWorkerWork(Worker: TBackgroundWorker);
    end;
  ```
- Put the cursor anywhere in the form declaration and press <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+C</kbd> for Code Completion; it will automatically add the shell code for the event handler for you to fill in.
- In the form's OnCreate event, create the `TBackgroundWorker` and assign the event in code:

  ```
  procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  begin
    BackgroundWorker := TBackgroundWorker.Create(Self);
    BackgroundWorker.OnWork := BackgroundWorkerWork;
    // Assign any other events to the BackgroundWorker here as well.
  end;
  ```

(In the future when you say something "doesn't work", explain **specifically** how it doesn't work, including any error messages you might have. When you have error messages, include the **exact** error message, and indicate when possible which line of your code caused the error. It's much easier to get answers to your questions if you give us the information you already have about the problem when asking.

Comment: Thank you but one thing, backgroundworker is a component, you can't see the backgroundworker in the Object Inspector tab... Is there another way the create the event?